Is it possible to protect haproxy and backends from a slow attack?
My goal is to keep as less open connections to the backends as possible. I am trying to mitigate this problem:

Attacker connects to haproxy
Sends the POST/GET request quickly
But then keeps the download speed very low (like 10 bytes per second)

If I understand correctly, haproxy will keep the connection to the backend server open until the client receives the complete response.
Right now, I'm solving this problem by having the following chain:
client -> haproxy -> nginx (for response buffering) -> haproxy -> backend servers (nginx + php-fpm)
I am curious if I'm doing it wrong and perhaps there is a more elegant solution. Perhaps there is a way to have haproxy buffer the response, so there would be no need for a nginx in the middle of the chain?
